# React Redux, dispatch action to add many elements from array at once

Tags: arrays, reactjs, redux, reducers

I have a React component which retrieves a list of leagues when it is mounted, and I would like to store each of those leagues as an array in the redux store.

Right now, I can do this, but the structure looks like this:

leagues ->

[0] ->

[0] -> league_0
   [1] -> league_1
   etc

That is, the retrieved league's array is stored entirely as a nested array within the first element of the league's array in the redux store.

How can I structure this so the leagues aren't all nested within that first element? Meaning the structure would just be:

leagues ->

[0] -> league_1

[1] -> league_2

etc.

Here's my action:

```
function setUserLeagues(leagues) {
    return {
        type: SET_USER_LEAGUES,
        leagues
    }
}
```

Here's my reducer:

```
const initialState = {
  leagues: []
};

export default (state = initialState, action = {}) => {
  switch(action.type) {
    case SET_USER_LEAGUES:
      return [
        action.leagues
      ]
    default: return state;
  }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: How are you are formatting this data on server side...?

Comment: If you are adding multiple items at a time you will have to take the a copy of the existing state and add to it...

Comment: It's rendered using Active Model Serializer from Ruby on Rails - it returns a JSON object with N leagues, rendered as a standard JSON list. And right, that's fine, although in this specific case I'm actually just overwriting anything that was there previously

Comment: so the leagues are already in an array of objects called league this is what you are setting as state you need to access this object in you reducer and and return only the objects, without the parent array....can you log what the logger is showing you for SET_USER_LEAGUES success but accessing that array instead of adding it as you receive it

Comment: I actually think I figured this out: I just do return state = action.leagues in the reducer

Comment: yes thats correct

Comment: the array is not needed since you have already structured your leagues in rails

Comment: right, thanks, appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

My own answer: It was quite simple, I just had to do:

```
state = action.leagues
```